# How do I convert System__ComObject to an image?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I'm using DSOFile to get the summary properties from some Crystal Reports report files. **SummaryProperties.Thumbnail** returns an object and I need to convert the object to an image so I can display it as a preview on my form. I have tried casting it to a **System.Drawing.Image** but I get an error "ImageConverter cannot convert from System.__ComObject."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a COM interface for images, IPicture or IPictureDisp, probably.  You could use the AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture or GetPictureFromIPictureDisp static method to make the conversion.

Comment: It took some more googling to find out I had to implement AxHost to use the GetPictureFromIPicture method, but I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a small wrapper class that what worked for me:

```
stdole.IPictureDisp iPictureDisp = row.Parent.Thumbnail;
pictureBox1.Image = IconTools.GetImage(iPictureDisp);
```

You'll want to use AxHost, as mentioned by Hans. It was a bit trickier to implement than I first thought though. Note that you'll want to use `AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture` rather than `GetPictureFromIPictureDisp`.

About [AxHost.GetPictureFromIPictureDisp:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost.getpicturefromipicturedisp)

> This method does not work correctly. You can use the
>   **GetPictureFromIPicture** method to convert an **IPictureDisp** object into an Image, however, because the **IPictureDisp** OLE
>   interface is a subset of the **IPicture** interface.

Here's the wrapper:

```
public class IconTools
{
    private class IconToolsAxHost : System.Windows.Forms.AxHost
    {
        private IconToolsAxHost() : base(string.Empty) { }

        public static stdole.IPictureDisp GetIPictureDispFromImage(System.Drawing.Image image)
        {
            return (stdole.IPictureDisp)GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
        }

        public static System.Drawing.Image GetImageFromIPicture(object iPicture)
        {
            return GetPictureFromIPicture(iPicture);
        }
    }

    public static stdole.IPictureDisp GetIPictureDisp(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {
        return IconToolsAxHost.GetIPictureDispFromImage(image);
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Image GetImage(stdole.IPicture iPicture)
    {
        return IconToolsAxHost.GetImageFromIPicture(iPicture);
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Image GetImage(stdole.IPictureDisp iPictureDisp)
    {
        return IconToolsAxHost.GetImageFromIPicture(iPictureDisp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up with. I get the thumbnail object and pass it to my IPictureDispHost class. The class implements a static method, Image GetPictureFromIPicture(object picture).